# Getting images from gallery, some images doesn't show even image path is obtained

Tags: android

I'm trying to fetch all images paths inside the gallery(including subfolders) Its working fine, but some of the images are failing to show as thumbnails

*obtaining all paths inside arraylist

```
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
    };
    final Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
            null, null,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final String imageLocation = cursor.getString(1);
        locations.add(imageLocation);


        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String tempLocation = cursor.getString(1);
            boolean fileExists = new File(tempLocation).isFile();
            if (fileExists) {
                locations.add(tempLocation);
            }
        }


        cursor.close();
```

*setting image inside ImageView

```
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mItems.get(position)));
    Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(uri)
            .resize(200, 200)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_media)
           .error(R.drawable.placeholder_error_media)
            .noFade()
            .into(mMediaThumb);
```

Comment: what do you mean by fail ?

Comment: It doesn't set the ImageView(mMediaThumb), even though the uri has value

Comment: get black image instead ?

Comment: Whatever is set inside .error

Comment: what error you getting

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
Picasso.with(Context).setLoggingEnabled(true);
```

To check if there is an error retrieving image in logcat.